# Propagating errors from C# dll

Tags: c#, dll, interop

The main question is simple. I have a c# dll I created to act as a plugin for an access solution. What would be a proper OO design pattern for returning error information from the dll to the solution?

I know I use to use things like SetLastError for dlls written in C, however this does not seem to be the optimum solution for an OO pattern. The basic setup is I have a class written in VBA which calls methods within the dll. The methods return true or false depending on whether or not they worked. I would like to be able to get more information as to the nature of the failure if the methods returned false however.

`

```
 interface IMyClass
 {
      bool MyMethod();
 }
 class MyClass: IMyClass
 {
      public bool MyMethod()
      {
           if(DoSomething() != null)
           {
                return true;
           }
           else
           {
                return false;
           }
      }
      private someDataType DoSomething()
      {
           try
           {
                Something;
                return someDataType;
           }
           catch(SomeException e)
           {
                //how do I return this information
                return null;
           }
      }
 }
```

`

Comment: [C# Basics Tutorial - Exception Handling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_exception_handling.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need  cross-boundary solution, use one suggested by Microsoft: [IErrorInfo interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221233(v=vs.85).aspx).

Implement IErrorInfo in the DLL and wrap all exporting function into try-catch:

```
try
{
  Something;
  return someDataType;
}
catch(SomeException e)
{
  SetErrorInfo(0, new MyErrorInfo(e.Message));
  return null;
}

[DllImport("oleaut32.dll")]
extern static int SetErrorInfo(uint dwReserved, IntPtr pErrorInfo);
```

In the application code call GetErrorInfo to obtain IErrorInfo pointer.
IErrorInfo may be consumed by C#, C++, VB etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, I think you want the first one:

- Catch it, rethrow a new exception with the inner exception set to the exception caught, let the solution handle the new exception, possibly a notification of the internal exception.
- Don't catch the exception at all, and let it propagate all its internals
- Catch it, log it, and do graceful recovery. Analyse the log afterwards

Comment: Is throwing across an interop boundary the way to do it? I thought about that but it just feels "dirty" to me. 

The main access project has a fully flushed out error logging and reporting system so I was hoping to avoid having the dll create a separate log file. I know there use to be a SetLastError function when using win32 dlls, has that design pattern been retired for managed interop?